# Website Builder with Custom Coding App

Tags: web-apps, software-development, web-development, self-hosted

I am a developer, but not yet a web developer.  I am looking for a website builder like Wix, Wordpress, or Squarespace that I can self-host.  The idea is that a web designer, or even myself, should be able to drag-and-drop edit the static pages, but the pages that are app-like should be programmed custom (while hooking into the style info of the drag and dropped static pages). My preference would be to code in Ruby or Python (and to avoid PHP).

What options are there to have a drag-and-drop editable website with some pages/parts that are app (custom coded)?

This will not be a typical ecommerce or blog app, hence the need for custom code.

Comment: Those close votes are because you are asking for "the best". If you edit the question to give a list of features which you require, you will get some help. Please read [ask]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking an opinion (of "the best")

Comment: I removed "the best"

Comment: But you are still mostly just saying "something like X,Y or Z", rather than giving a list of the features that you need (or what you don't like about X, Y and Z that prevents you using them). The more information that you can give us, the more likely that we can help you

Comment: Ok. Whatever. Close the question. Thanks.

Comment: Dude, don't "whatever" me - I'm the one who is trying to help you here. I have not voted to close, as I hope that you can edit the question to tell us what you actually want. Your profile shows that you know enough about how the S.E sites work. Please, just read [read], edit the question and I am sure that it will be answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't have enough info when I wrote the question.  I just voted to close it.

Comment: I am fairly sure that I asked a similar question myself once. I will search around & see what I can find.  Saying you don't want PHP will probably reduce the candidates a lot.  What about Node.JS?

Answer (score 1):

Camaleon CMS looks like an interesting option for Ruby on Rails. http://camaleon.tuzitio.com/